# How to know relation between object_id in cscart_images_links and cscart_products table?

Tags: php, database, cs-cart

I want to fetch image into my custom database table in cs cart website. I have made one seller admin panel where user have to upload product with image and same data will goes to cscart_products table. But I couldn't find way to fetch image as there is no link between products and image table.